# Placing a UImageView in a cell programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I've got a `UITableViewCell *cell`, which has a `UIImageView *image` and a `UILabel *description` subviews. Description label held the upper part of the cell, I need to locate the `UIImageView`between the label and the bottom edge. Here's my code:

```
CGFloat bottomTextY = cell.labelDescription.frame.origin.y + cell.labelDescription.frame.size.height;
CGFloat newImageY = bottomTextY + (cell.frame.size.height - bottomTextY) / 2;

cell.image.center = CGPointMake(cell.image.center.x, newImageY);
```

But every time the position is different, it's not strictly between the label and the edge. Autolayout is off. Please, help me!)

Comment: Do you have some screenshots to demonstrate this maybe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your life easier, you should design your cell (prototype cell) within the storyboard. That cell will include your two fields (image and text). Then **tag** your fields and  in

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

add something that looks like :

```
UIImageView * imageView = (UIImageView *)[cell viewWithTag:CELL_TAG_PHOTO];
imageView .image      = [self.photoSource objectForKey:key] ;
```

Of course, the tag (number) of each element has to be unique since this is how the elements are identified (define them with `#define CELL_TAG_PHOTO (tag_number)`)

Answer (score 0):

Set the frame of the UIImageView, not the center property.

Example:

```
    cell.imageView .frame = CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetMaxY(cell.descriptionLabel.frame), cell.frame.size.width, cell.frame.size.height - CGRectGetMaxY(cell.descriptionLabel.frame));
```